# Django - ForeignKey Filter Choices

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'd like to filter the choices that a user can choose in my ForeignKey Field.
I basically have a ForeignKey for the subject of the Test and the actual topic of the Test. These topics come from a different model and are linked to a subject. Now I'd like to filter the choices to only include the topics that are linked to the currently selected subject. Is that possible and if so, how?

models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    thema = models.ForeignKey(Thema, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    school_class = models.ForeignKey(SchoolClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    grade = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(6)], blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.school_class and self.student:
            self.school_class = self.student.klasse
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Thema(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    thema = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Subject(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

The Problem if I use this:

```
# thema model @staticmethod     
def return_thema(subject):         
   themen = Thema.objects.filter(subject=subject)         
   return {'thema': themen}  

#test model 
   thema = models.ForeignKey(Thema, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,limit_choices_to=Thema.return_thema(subject))
```

Is that I get the Error:
`django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`
Meaning I can't get the objects of the Thema Model while the models are loading

EDIT (for Swift):
That seemed to resolve the error when trying to makemigrations, but I now get this error, when visiting the admin portal to create a new Test:

```
File "/Users/di/Code/Schule/GymnasiumApp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1404, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Can you post the `Subject` model please?

Comment: Posted the Subject Model

Comment: Thank you. Please see my comment on my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for ideally would be `ForeignKey.limit_choices_to`

Please see the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

You can limit the choices available at a model level, which is enforced throughout the django app, including forms automatically.

**Edit because OP provided more information**

Ok so I believe if you declare the thema field on the test model like so, it will solve the issue, and I will explain why after:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    thema = models.ForeignKey(Thema, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to=Q('thema_set__subject_set'))
    school_class = models.ForeignKey(SchoolClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    grade = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(6)], blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.school_class and self.student:
            self.school_class = self.student.klasse
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

We are essentially telling Django to evaluate the relationship between the limited choices "lazily" I.e. when the form is loaded dynamically. Django forms will look at the `limit_choices_to` field argument and apply it to the available choices.

I'm not 100% about the relationship of your models so the `Q(...)` I added, might actually need to be `Q('subject_set')`

Comment: The Problem if I use this:
`# thema model
@staticmethod
    def return_thema(subject):
        themen = Thema.objects.filter(subject=subject)
        return {'thema': themen}

#test model
thema = models.ForeignKey(Thema, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to=Thema.return_thema(subject))`
Is that I get the Error:
`django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`
Meaning I can't get the objects of the Thema Model while the models are loading.

Comment: Can you add this to your question please? It's hard to read

Comment: Just wondering if you can format you comment into the question so its readable at all?

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it.

Comment: Hey @Dan I edited the answer, can you see the output of my changes to your test model please?

Comment: Hey! I tried the new approach and edited my question for more infos!

Comment: You might have to rollback the previous migration aswell

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, it seems to need two arguments in the Q() Object.

Comment: Yes, it does indeed, maybe add an `=F(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use django forms you can use the model choice field.
In your view you can set your queryset of this choicefield. Zo you can filter it.

```
fields['your model field'].queryset = yourmodel.objects.filter(your filter parameters)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is also problem in save method also. Aren't you need to write the name of the model inside like

```
return super(<modelName>).save(*args, **kwargs)
```